# How to concatenate strings to build full path?

Tags: python, string, path, concatenation

```
path = r'C:\Program Files\1\1.exe'
```

I can run a program using the path above. I don't want to hardcode it, so I'm trying to use a variable in place of the `1`s. This is what I came up with:

```
variable1 = '1'
path = r'C:\Program Files\ , +variable1 , +\, +variable1, +.exe'
```

This doesn't work. How do I make it work?

Comment: Use `os.path.join()`. And either use `/` or raw strings, otherwise the backslash starts escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

```
variable1 = '1'

path = 'C:\\Program Files\\'+variable1+'\\'+variable1+'.exe'
```

\ is special char so you need to escape it with another \

Comment: Use a raw string so it's not special.

Comment: thanks , i didn't see the r :p